# Issue On Creating Simple PHP MVC App

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller

Can you please let me know how I Can create a very simple OOP MVC app in PHP to get some user data from a form like this

```
<form>
First Name:<br>
<input type="text" name="firstname">
<br>
Last Name:<br>
<input type="text" name="lastname">
<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

and echo it out like

> ```
> Your Name Full Name is XXXX,XXXXXX.
> ```

I have a file structure like

[image]

and in `init.php`

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class){
     require_once 'controllers/'.$class.'.php';
     require_once 'views/'.$class.'.php';
     require_once 'models/'.$class.'.php';
});

Visitor = new Visitor();
```

now lets say if I create a `m_visitor.php` including `Visitor()`class in Model, how I can create associated class(es) or File(s) in Controller and View? and how I can sync them to get and set data from the Model to View and Controller?

This would be a great help to me to really understand how to deal with OOP - MVC structure in PHP. Thanks

Comment: Can you please let me know why did you down vote my question?

Comment: Would you consider using a 'ready made', simple, mvc framework that is already written and tested? A sample list can be found here: [A Comparison of PHP Micro-frameworks](https://xybu.me/a-comparison-of-php-micro-frameworks/).

Comment: @Behseini I am sorry to inform you about this, but what you have is nothing like "MVC". You basically have there a template and some table abstractions.

Comment: Thanks teresko , that s exactly my question to how to do it?